# Remove duplicates from an unsorted linked list. I used ArrayList to solve

Tags: arraylist, singly-linked-list, hashset

Given an unsorted linked list of N nodes. The task is to remove duplicate elements from this unsorted Linked List. When a value appears in multiple nodes, the node which appeared first should be kept, all others duplicates are to be removed.

Example 1:

Input:
N = 4
value[] = {5,2,2,4}

Output: 5 2 4

Explanation: Given linked list elements are
5->2->2->4, in which 2 is repeated only.
So, we will delete the extra repeated
elements 2 from the linked list and the
resultant linked list will contain 5->2->4

It's a question on GFG and I passed 405 test cases but on 406th test case it shows 'Time limit exceeded Error'. Is it like ArrayList is taking too long to traverse every element again and again?
Then I tried using HashSet with the same logic and it worked perfectly and passes all test cases.

```
class Solution
{
    //Function to remove duplicates from unsorted linked list.
    public Node removeDuplicates(Node head) 
    {
         // Your code here
         Node prev = head;
        Node temp = head.next;
        ArrayList<Integer> val = new ArrayList<>();
        val.add(head.data);
        while(temp != null){
            if(val.contains(temp.data)){
                prev.next = temp.next;   
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            else{
                val.add(temp.data);
                temp = temp.next;
                prev = prev.next;
            }
            
        }
        return head;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While your logic is indeed correct, it is not the most optimal solution.

Consider this example:

Input: 5 -> 2 -> 2 -> 2 -> 2 -> 3

Your Result steps would be:

```
5 -> 2 -> 2 -> 2 -> 2 -> 3
5 -> 2 -> 2 -> 2 -> 3
5 -> 2 -> 2 -> 3
5 -> 2 -> 3
```

Instead of doing the pointer writes so many times, you could keep going forward till you encounter the first not-seen-so-far node and make your pointers point to the new node directly.

Moreover, instead of using an ArrayList, you could use a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashSet.html). The `.contains()` method in ArrayList has a time complexity of `O(n)` where `n` is the number of elements in the ArrayList. As you do this operation `M` times for each loop, your order is going to be `O(mn)`. Set has a time complexity of `O(1)` (Constant lookup time), So if you the do the operation M times, it will be M times `O(1)` which is whole lot faster.

Perhaps this code might help:

```
class Solution
{
    //Function to remove duplicates from unsorted linked list.
    public Node removeDuplicates(Node head) 
    {
        if(head == NULL) { // BASE CASE
            return head;
        }
        Node prev = head;
        Node temp = head.next;
        boolean shouldDelete = false;
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(head.data);
        while(temp != null){
            if(set.contains(temp.data)){
                shouldDelete = true; // Set this to true to make sure any duplicates at the end is also taken care of.
            }
            else{
                shouldDelete = false; // Set this to false as we have encountered a not-seen-so-far node.
                set.add(temp.data);
                prev.next = temp;
                prev = temp;
            }
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        if(shouldDelete) { // There is duplicate elements in the end that has not been trimmed because we never encountered a not-seen-so-far element. So set it to NULL
            prev.next = NULL;
        }
        return head;
    }
}
```